# Get Clients Assigned to Class Using SQL and the API

Tags: sql

I need to to select a list of ClientIds and RSSIDs from the API where a Client is Signed up for a class that starts on a specific date and time. I have been able to create the SQL command to pull back the correct list of ClassIds, but I am having trouble with the rest. Based on the limited information available for the API and specifically the feature to directly call SQL commands, I thought this would be the best way to accomplish it, but it doesn't seem to be pulling back the correct Clients. Do you have any thoughts as to why this is not working or a better way to execute this?

```
stringList = "classId1, classId2, classId3" 

SELECT v.ClientId, c.RSSID 
FROM [VISIT DATA] v 
LEFT JOIN Clients c ON v.ClientId = c.ClientID 
WHERE v.ClassId in (" + stringList + @") 
GROUP BY v.ClientId, c.RSSID"
```

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: Are you asking about how to build a REST/HTTP API for this or how to use some database client API?